# Unable to retrieve data from firebase for login.java. No errors in the gradles but the signin function isn't working

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have added all the strings, private booleans in the Signup.java and properly added all the firebase dependencies. Plus, Added the codes in Login.java to retrieve all the firebase data after successful signup. However, there is no error showing in the codes but still, the sign-in screen functionalites aren't working. When I click on "Signin" button the apps showing me "This app has stopped"

Here's the code that I have written on login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button callSignUp, reg_btn;
    TextInputLayout username, password;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        callSignUp = findViewById(R.id.signupscreen);

        callSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, SignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });


        //All elements Hooks

        username = findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
        password = findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        reg_btn = findViewById(R.id.reg_btn);
    }

    private Boolean validateUsername() {
        String val = username.getEditText().getText().toString();


        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            username.setError("Please enter your username");
            return false;
        } else {
            username.setError(null);
            username.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validatePassword() {
        String val = password.getEditText().getText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()) {
            password.setError("Please enter your password");
            return false;
        } else {
            password.setError(null);
            password.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void loginUser(View view) {
        //validate user login
        if (!validateUsername() | !validatePassword()) {
            return;
        } else {
            isUser();
        }
    }

    private void isUser() {

        final String userEnteredUsername = username.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        final String userEnteredPassword = password.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(userEnteredUsername);

        checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    username.setError(null);
                    username.setErrorEnabled(false);

                    String passwordFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("password").getValue(String.class);

                    if (passwordFromDB.equals(userEnteredPassword)) {


                        String nameFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        String emailFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("email").getValue(String.class);
                        String usernameFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("username").getValue(String.class);
                        String phoneNoFromDB = dataSnapshot.child(userEnteredUsername).child("phoneNo").getValue(String.class);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfile.class);

                        intent.putExtra("name", nameFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("username", usernameFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("phoneNo", phoneNoFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("password", passwordFromDB);

                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        password.setError("Wrong Password");
                    }
                } else {
                    username.setError("Opps! No Such User Exist!");
                    username.requestFocus();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
    //Call SignUp Screen
    public void callSignUpScreen(View view) {
        //To call next activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, SignUp.class);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why the issue is happening?

Thanks

Comment: If your app crashes there will be an error message and stack trace in its logcat output. Find those and include them in your question by clicking the edit link under it please. It'll likely also help if you include a sample of the relevant JSON under `users` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).